# Converting an excel IF formula to a Powerpivot DAX formula

Tags: excel-formula, formula, powerpivot, dax

Im struggling to find a solution for a formula conversion from excel to powerpivot. 
Its relatively simple in excel. I want to return a value that says >8000 or <8000 depending on the value of column A (measured depth)
Here is the formula in excel 
=IF(A2>8000,"> 8,000",(IF(A2<8001,"<8,000",IF(A2=0,"UNDEFINED"))))

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks
David

Comment: David, can you send a sample of the data you work with?

Comment: Hello Petr, Here is a link to sample date with column D containing the IF formula. [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GR2V0Qc797EPetJBHUtNc4IycxsuOL3krAcnRT5Urtw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

`=IF([columnName]>8000,"> 8,000",IF([columnName]<8001,"<8,000","UNDEFINED"))`

Comment: Hi Tycho, thats what i tried but it would not work for me in power pivot

Comment: Tycho your formula above actually worked perfectly. I had an issue with the data itself not reading as a whole number. Once that was changed your IF statement worked a charm.

Comment: Glad to here you solved it by now! I know PowerPivot can be frustrating, its error messages can be unclear at times...